# Generic Epic using Redux-Observable

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I just started using Redux-Observable. I want to make a generic epic that requests data from the server. I want multiple requests with same action and id to be debounced. However, I'm not sure how to do this without creating multiple epics.

```
const TYPE_IFEXISTS_REQUEST = 'IFEXISTS_REQUEST';
export const IFEXISTS_REQUEST = (id, value) =>
  ({ type: TYPE_IFEXISTS_REQUEST, id, value });
export const IFEXISTS_EPIC = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(TYPE_IFEXISTS_REQUEST)
    .debounceTime(5000) // ERROR: debounces based on action type and not id
    .mergeMap(action =>
      fromPromise(api.get(`/api/exists/${action.id}/${action.value}`))
        .map(({ data }) => IFEXISTS_SUCCESS(action.id, data))
        .catch(() => of(IFEXISTS_FAILURE(action.id, 'Server error'))));
```

How is it possible to create a generic epic that debounces based on both action and id?

---

Update: Never knew about GroupBy. It worked well with switchMap. The following is was I used.

```
action$
    .ofType(TYPE_IFEXISTS_REQUEST)
    .groupBy(action => action.id)
    .mergeMap(actionByIdGroup$ => 
        actionByIdGroup$
            .debounceTime(5000) // debounces based on action id
            .switchMap(action =>
                fromPromise(api.get(`/api/exists/${action.id}/${action.value}`))
                    .map(({ data }) => IFEXISTS_SUCCESS(action.id, data))
                    .catch(() => of(IFEXISTS_FAILURE(action.id, 'Server error')))
            );
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [groupBy](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#groupby) operator:

```
  action$
    .ofType(TYPE_IFEXISTS_REQUEST)
    .groupBy(action => action.id)
    .mergeMap(actionByIdGroup$ => 
        actionByIdGroup$
            .debounceTime(5000) // debounces based on action id
            .mergeMap(action =>
                fromPromise(api.get(`/api/exists/${action.id}/${action.value}`))
                    .map(({ data }) => IFEXISTS_SUCCESS(action.id, data))
                    .catch(() => of(IFEXISTS_FAILURE(action.id, 'Server error')))
            );
    )
```

The *actionByIdGroup$* is a Grouped Observable of the same action ids. Meaning, only actions with the same id will be part of the same stream. In this case, the *debounceTime* will be applied for actions with the same id.

Comment: I always wondered how you do something like this but with a cancelation. Can you please provide an example if you know todo it :)